# visual basic get sum from expression in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am developing a calculator in VB 2010 where a user clicks on the button and the textbox should contain the value of the textbox clicked. I want that if "Enter" button is clicked it should display the results from the expression in textbox. I tried using these codes and it is not working. (suppose that the expression box contains maybe " 9 + 7 - 5")

```
ResultBox.text=ExpressionBox.text
```

and

```
ResultBox.text=val(ExpressionBox.text)
```

I get the string as it is written in the ExpressionBox. How can I get those results?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic sample.

Works for +, -, * and /.

Evaluates from left to right.

Further more you can develop yourself

I've put it on keyDown event so that it evaluates when user hits enter

```
Function evaluate(val1 As Double, val2 As Double, opr As String) As Double
    Dim result As Double = 0
    Select Case opr
        Case "+"
            result = val1 + val2
        Case "-"
            result = val1 - val2
        Case "*"
            result = val1 * val2
        Case "/"
            result = val1 / val2
    End Select
    Return result
End Function

Function evaluate(expression As String) As String
    Dim prevVal As String = ""
    Dim result As Double = 0
    Dim isStart As Boolean = True
    Dim prevExpression As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To expression.Length - 1
        Dim curChar As String = expression.Substring(i, 1)
        Select Case curChar
            Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."
                prevVal += curChar
            Case "+", "-", "*", "/"
                prevExpression = curChar
                If isStart Then
                    isStart = False
                    result = Val(prevVal)
                    prevVal = ""
                Else
                    result = evaluate(result, Val(prevVal), prevExpression)
                    prevVal = ""
                End If
        End Select
    Next
    result = evaluate(result, Val(prevVal), prevExpression)
    Return result.ToString()
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox1.Text = evaluate(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you are correct but i cant understand the codes to implement them in my codes.

Comment: I dont understand whether u are asking how to implement it to your project or not. If so then all you need to do is just add the two functions named 'evaluate' from the codes above to your form. Then write ResultBox.text = evaluate (ExpressionBox.text) to the handler where you need it..